# Yii Relations from grandchild to grandFather

Tags: yii

I have the following scheme:
[image]

Can I connect Company with users and users with company? Saying connect I mean a relation in User model which will returns me the all the companies and all the branches for a specific role for the current user.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do that with Yii (or any modern MVC framework).

Make sure you have the relations defined in their respective model classes (the code assumes you're using Yii 1).

```
Class User extends CActiveRecord
{
  ...
  public function relations(){
    return array(
      'role' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Roles', 'user_id'),
    );
  }
  ...
}
```

Define appropriate relations in your other classes and you should be able to access them like this...

```
// Defined relation is BELONGS_TO
$belongsToModel = $model->definedRelation;

// Defined relation is HAS_MANY
$arrayOfCActiveRecords = $model->definedRelation;
```

If the defined relation is HAS_MANY, you can iterate over the array and access the individual records.

**Update:**
According to your comments, the only simple way to do what you want is to give your roles a branch_id (and make sure your branches have a company_id).  If a particular role is common to multiple branches, you can, of course, give them the same description but in the database they need to be distinguished from one another because they are, in fact, different roles.

Since you can't assign a role_id to a user nor a user_id to a role, you will have to create an associative table to join them (you can make a model for it if you wish; visit [this thread](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php?/topic/6905-please-test-my-ar-enhancement-automatically-sync-many-many-table-when-calling-save/) in the Yii Forum for more info).

Once you do that, connecting a user to a company should go something like this...

```
// in your User model...
private $_roles = array();

public function getRoles(){
    if(isset($this) && get_class($this) == __CLASS__){
        $query = "select * from users_roles where user_id = {$this->id}";
        $this->_roles = Yii::app()->db->createCommand($query)->queryAll();
    }
    return $this->_roles;
}
```

Now you should be able to call `$roles = $user->roles` and iterate over the roles, get the branches and then get the companies.

Comment: The problem is that there is many to many connection User - Roles. So Its difficult to navigate from user to company via ordinary way!

Comment: Your chart indicates that there is a BELONGS_TO relationship between User and Role.  You should probably update that if it's incorrect.

Comment: Why don't you directly connect a company or branch to a user?  It seems like a natural relationship.

Comment: One user can have only one role per branch. From the other hand there are different branches for any company and the user can have different role for each of them